# Zoom in embedded IE affecting standalone IE

Tags: c++, internet-explorer, browser, zooming

I have program with Internet Explorer embedded into it.

In some cases I need to adjust the zoom level on my embedded IE.
I'm using ExecWB command with OLECMDID_OPTICAL_ZOOM to do that.
This is working grate, but for some reason it's also affecting to zoom level of the standalone IE browser (So that if I set the zoom to 150% on my app - the next tab that will be opened in regular IE will also have a zoom level of 150%).
This is also true when I'm using the CTRL + mouse wheel option to affect the zoom on my program.

I've checked with "Slim browser" and with the embedded browser in visual studio and they don't have the same affect (zooming in them doesn't affect the standalone IE browser).

Is there some way to disconnect the zoom on my program from the zoom on the standalone IE?

(I'm using IWebBrowser2 interface for my browser instance).

Thanks!!

Comment: Anyone? some ideas?

Answer (score 0):

No , it is impossible
i guess zoom factor share on variable..

may be u can set ie option to reset zoom.

[Internet Options -> Advanced tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r23hN.jpg)